# NSTextField in table view with specific configuration doesn't enable undo

Tags: cocoa

After typing anything in a custom text field with undo support, when opening the Edit menu, the undo item is disabled. It seems that setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false`, a `formatter`, `allowsEditingTextAttributes=true` and calling `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` in `textDidChange(_:)` causes this behaviour.

Is this expected, or is there a workaround?

Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
        let textField = MyTextField()
        textField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.formatter = MyFormatter()
        textField.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
        view.addSubview(textField)
    }

}

class MyTextField: NSTextField {
    
    override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        super.textDidChange(notification)
        super.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
}

class MyFormatter: Formatter {
    
    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
        return obj as? String
    }
    
    override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
        obj?.pointee = string as NSString
        return true
    }
    
}
```